# Methods of declaring a variable in shell script

Tags: shell, variables, declaration

What is the difference between the following two methods of declaring a variable in shell script?

```
var='some/path'

var=${var:-"some/path"}
```

Comment: Here's another way: `: ${var:="some/path"}`

Answer (score 0):

```
#this will set var value with some/path, 
#no matter var is empty or not (overwrite)
var='some/path' 


# this will set value of var to "some/path" 
#only if var is empty/or not declared yet.
var=${var:-"some/path"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var='some/path'
```

Will always set var to some/path

```
var=${var:-"some/path"}
```

Will only set var to some/path if var if not already set. If it is set, its value will not change.